# Specifying unknown dependent in randomForest prediction R

Tags: r, random-forest

Hi I want to use the regression predictions from randomForest.  I want to make predictions for observations I know the depedent variable of, but I dont want the program to know that.  Can I just specify the dependent as NA in my folds?  Basically, how do I get predictions for an unknown...  sorry, if stupid question but I just want to be sure that its treating it correctly.

edit:
Yeah my code just errored.  It doesn't like NA as dependent variable.

Comment: `predict(model, newdata = datayouwanttopredict)` and `?predict.randomForest`

Comment: Why are you putting an dependent variable in the input to a predict method? And do post your code. (This is a _coding_ site.)